# Need directions

Tags: android, ios, directions

I need some directions and advice. :)

I have a project for a mobile app in mind (look below), but am confused about all the different programming languages, frameworks and so. Confused about what to focus on.

Also, I'm not sure if I should focus on a solution specifically for this project or just try to get good at developing mobile apps in general?

I have learned the basics of JavaScript and Swift. Have never tried working with a framework.

The app has to be able to do the following:

- Store user data (strings and numbers)
- Show various graphs and stats based on the user data
- Look like a native iOS/Android app (e.g. like iTunes and App Store with the menu at the bottom)
- Send push messages to the user
- Ideally work for both iOS and Android

I’m of course looking for as easy and fast a solution as possible, but more important is that the solution looks and works like a quality app.

So, which solutions would be best for the project above? And what about developing apps in general? (or does it vary from app to app?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question, and I would suggest getting familiar with iOS/ Android development in general before making your own app.

There are tons of great tutorials out there on how to do both, I would suggest getting started with either one based on what equipment you have available and what you're familiar with.

If you want to make an app that runs on both platforms you could make it in HTML5, but I'd suggest making a native iOS app in either Obj-C or Swift, and a native Android app in Java.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I want to start with iOS, you would suggest that I start getting better at e.g. Swift and not focusing on frameworks until later? And also you would suggest making an app from scratch for both iOS and Android (when I get more familiar with development)?

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't do both at once. I personally recommend raywenderlich.com, where you can buy their iOS Apprentice series and get started with that. Once you're done with that, you can go into more advanced iOS development/ Swift programming. 

And yes, I suggest making an app from scratch for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks! And will I learn about both programming and frameworks at raywenderlich.com? I'm not even sure if it's necessary to learn both ... :) That's how confused about the process I am. Also, will I learn about monetizing my apps at that site, or should I look elsewhere for that?

Comment: Yes you will learn both about frameworks and programming at raywenderlich. They go hand in hand :) Don't think too much about terms and such haha, just enjoy the learning process. They definitely have some tutorials for monetizing your app too, but I'd look elsewhere for that. But you shouldn't focus on that until you learn development.

Comment: Great, I'll focus on the process, which is also what I prefer. I was just confused about how to initiate the process. Different languages, frameworks, learning sites and so on. So much information out there. But the site you recommended seems like specializing in mobile app - which is a big plus imo - unlike some of the other learning sites which try to cover a wider palette. Do you have a link for where to look for monetizing-tutorials? (AFTER learning development of course! ;))

Comment: There are millions of ways you can monetize mobile applications, so there won't just be one master tutorial out there. Here's a good intro so you know what to search for in the future: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/opportunities/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alek! Wish I could vote for your answer, but I don't have enough 'reputation' yet. I'm already working on the first tutorial of 'iOS Apprentice'. Hope I can draw on your knowledge, when I'm through the series. :)

Comment: Hi Alek! Just finished the first tutorial in 'iOS Apprentice' and really like it. It gave me a very good understanding of how to create an app from a-z. But do you think I should continue with Swift after React Native has been released? I would eventually like to make cross-platform apps, so is JS and React Native the way to go now? (should I make a new question for this?)

Comment: I suggest sticking with Obj-C or Swift (pref Obj-C), and then go from there. Don't try to learn it all at once. Get good at something, make some apps, and then take it from there. If you want a better answer, ask a new question :)